# Do not show previous input in html textarea

Tags: html, forms, post

This question is very basic and simple.

How can I make it where the textarea will not show previous input.

```
 <form action="" method="post">
 <textarea> Person's input </textarea>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="post">
 </form>
```

After using the textarea a few times I started noticing the previous input I've entered. Is there any way to get rid of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `autocomplete` attribute of an `input` tag to off to prevent the browser from showing the previous inputs.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

And for `textarea`

```
<textarea autocomplete="off">text</textarea>
```

You can also use `autocomplete` for a complete `form`.